# How to print properties of custom object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to return an array of `prop: value` of a custom object with `myObject[stringProp]` syntax. And I get Error like this:

```
     TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{} | EmployeeListDataRow'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{} | EmployeeListDataRow'.
```

```
  <h1>
    {Object.keys(currentEmployee).map((prop) => {
      return `${prop}: ${currentEmployee[prop]}\n`;
    })}
  </h1>
```

`currentEmployee` has interface like this:

```
export interface EmployeeListDataRow extends Object {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  startDate: Date;
  status: string;
  manager: string;
  title: string;
  account: string;
  team: string;
  rate: number;
  totalComp: number;
  gm: number;
  ebit: number;
  billable: string;
  phone: string;
  skills: string;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the 'extends Object" on the interface or using  return `${prop}: ${(currentEmployee as EmployeeListDataRow)[prop]}\n`;

Comment: share your `tsconfig`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you haven't explicitly told TypeScript that `EmployeeListDataRow` can be indexed by a string. You need to modify your interface to tell TypeScript your interface is string indexable:

```js
export interface EmployeeListDataRow {  // no need to extend Object
  [key: string]: number | string | Date;   // this is an index signature
  id: number;
  name: string;
  startDate: Date;
  status: string;
  manager: string;
  title: string;
  account: string;
  team: string;
  rate: number;
  totalComp: number;
  gm: number;
  ebit: number;
  billable: string;
  phone: string;
  skills: string;
}
```